# цикл с записью в массив

Tags: php

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    $x = rand(1, 100);
    if (($x % 33) == 0) {
        // 3 % вероятности
        $deg = 300;

    } else if (($x % 14) == 0) {
        // 7% вероятности
        $deg = 70;
    } else if (($x % 3) == 0) {
        // 30% вероятности
        $deg = 240;
    } else {

        $x = rand(1, 4);
        // 15 %
        if ($x = 1) {
            $deg = 150;

        } else if ($x = 2) {

            $deg = 120;

        } else if ($x = 3) {

            $deg = 30;


        } else if ($x = 4) {

            $deg = 340;

        }
    }
}
```

есть такой код, мне нужно выполнить этот код N количество раз, и записать в массив, то есть $arr = ['3%' => 'Выпало столько то раз'], что бы при каждой итерации прибавлялось значение, как это реализовать ?

Comment: `$arr[$key]++;` только проверяйте существует ли ключ, если нет, то `$arr[$key] = 0;`

Comment: мне в каждом цикле задавать эту переменную ?

Comment: Задавать значение нуль, только если такого ключа в массиве нет. Если ключи в массиве все заранее известны, то можете заполнить массив начальным значением до цикла. А в цикле только инкрементить нужные значения.